# Slack integration. Alert levels

Tags: google-fabric

[image]

What meening this levels ?

I don't find any explanation in docs

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impact levels take into account the number of total crashes and the number of users affected by a crash. We analyze these values and determine the impact based on a 5 point scale.

Comment: Can we see a formula?

Comment: The formula is complex and we don't share it publicly.

Comment: @alexizamerican Could you explain what the number mean? 1 - one user affected, 5 - 10,000 users affected and so on. Don't need the formula just need to understand the common concept.